# How to access data of a loaded resource file in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, fstream

I finally made it to load a binary resource successfully in C++.

However my knowledge is not sufficient to access the data directly. Therefore I use other code which is better known to me, but for which I have to save the resource once again to disk before. How to process the resource directly in memory without the intermediate steps ? See code attached. Somebody can support ? Thanks

```
#include <windows.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
char buffer [8192];

int main()
{
        HRSRC myResource = ::FindResource(NULL, "BIN1", RT_RCDATA); 
        unsigned int myResourceSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
        HGLOBAL myResourceData = ::LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
        void* pMyBinaryData = ::LockResource(myResourceData);

        // HOW TO ACCESS "BIN1" RESOURCE DATA IN MEMORY ..
        // I WOULD LIKE TO REMOVE / REPLACE THE FOLLOWING:
        std::ofstream f("original.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        f.write((char*)pMyBinaryData, myResourceSize);
        f.close();
        ifstream file("original.bin", std::ios::binary);
        // INSTEAD SAVING AND RELOADING FROM DISK AGAIN ??

        ofstream out("modified.bin", std::ios::binary);

        while( file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)), file.gcount()>0 ) {           
            int i=0;
            while (i < sizeof(buffer)) {       
                buffer[i] = buffer[i] ^ 'A';
                i++;
                }
        out.write(buffer, file.gcount());
            }
}
```

Comment: `pMyBinaryData` points to the resource data in memory, although it is read-only. If you cast the pointer to `char*` (e.g. `char* pReadOnlyData = (char*)pMyBinaryData;`) you can read it a character at a time. Use `memcpy` to copy it to another buffer if you want to be able to modify it.

Comment: What does "dev c++" have to do with anything?

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. Coming closer to the solution.
Have added now: char* pReadOnlyData = (char*)pMyBinaryData;
And thought I could do something like following:
printf("%s", pReadOnlyData[i]);
But nothing printed to the screen, just for doing just a simple test :-).
Further tests with tyring to write to a file tomorrow.

Comment: @Jesper: You are right. it is general, not related to Dev C++.

Comment: @Key111 your resource is binary, and binary data frequently contains 0x00 bytes in it. You can't treat binary data as text data, so don't use string functions to work with binary data. Also, `pReadOnlyData[i]` is a single `char`, so you can't print it using `%s` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`LockResource()` gives you direct access to the resource data in memory. You can use the pointer however you need, just keep in mind that it is a pointer to read-only data.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    HRSRC myResource = ::FindResource(NULL, "BIN1", RT_RCDATA); 
    DWORD myResourceSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
    HGLOBAL myResourceData = ::LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
    char* pMyBinaryData = (char*) ::LockResource(myResourceData);

    std::ofstream out("modified.bin", std::ios::binary);
    char buffer [8192];

    DWORD i = 0;
    while (i < myResourceSize) {           
        DWORD bufsize = std::min<DWORD>(myResourceSize-i, sizeof(buffer));
        CopyMemory(buffer, pMyBinaryData+i, bufsize);
        for (int j = 0; j < bufsize; ++j) {       
            buffer[j] ^= 'A';
        }
        out.write(buffer, bufsize);
        i += bufsize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy. Looks nice and short, however can't compile it due to an [Error]:
Test.cpp:18:66: **error: no matching function for call to 'min(DWORD, long long unsigned int)'**
DWORD bufsize = std::min(myResourceSize-i, sizeof(buffer));
                                                          ^
Test.cpp:18:66: note: candidates are:
In file included from D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
../ios:40, ../ostream:38,   ../iostream:39,

Comment: Sorry. Should have done some further research on it before. This error was easy to solve, as just 2 different types have been compared with "min" .. have changed the one type now to: "long long unsigned int myResourceSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);" and it seems to work! GREAT! **Thanks to all again** for the support. This was really a great help. THANKS

Comment: @Key111 using `size_t` instead of `long long unsigned int` would be cleaner. Specifying the type that `std::min()` should take in would be even cleaner. I have updated my example.

Comment: I will give this a try as well. Anyhow, I'm so happy that it works finally. You saved me from wasting further hours and days on this problem I had. A BIG THANK-YOU once again.